# HTML5 History in combination with form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history, html5-history

I got a question regarding the history functionality. The problem that I have is that whenever I navigate towards another page the history got erased. Which results in a `originalEvent.state` with value `null` instead of the stateid.

Let me explain myself by some code:

```
 function SetStateId(stateId, addState) {
     $("#stateId").val(stateId);
     data = { stateid: stateId };
     if (addState)
    {
        console.log("History added. StateId: " + stateId);
        history.pushState(data, "StateId: " + stateId, window.location);
    }
    else {
        console.log("History replaced. StateId: " + stateId);
        history.replaceState(data, "StateId: " + stateId, window.location);
    }
 }



 function setupPopState() {
     console.log("setupPopState ");

     $(window).bind('popstate', function (event)
     {
         PopStateEvent(event);
     });   
 }
```

and my HTML Looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<input type="hidden" name="stateId" id="stateId" value="1">
<script>SetStateId(1, true,"");setupPopState();</script>

<a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
```

**page2.html**

```
<script>
    function callHistory(){
        SetStateId(2, true,""); 
        setupPopState();            
    }

</script>
<input type="hidden" name="stateId" id="stateId" value="2">
<script>callHistory();</script>
```

Whenever the index page is loaded the SetStateId function is called and the stateID is added to the history with value 1. It then automatically goes to the setupPopState() event en binds the popstate event to the window. Looking at the content of the event I see that in this case the `originalEvent.state` contains an object.

Now when I press the hyperlink I navigate towards my page2.html. The history is pushed with a new stateid: 2. Now comes the tricky part. When I want to go back and press the back button somehow the event within the popstate binding got the following data: `orginalEvent.state = null`; It looks like the history got erased when the page is reloaded (in my case navigated towards a different page).

Does anyone know why?